# Converting a char to binary bits, i.e.: 'a' to binary equivalent

Tags: c, function, binary, bit, binary-data

I'm hoping to get a quick hand with my code. I need to convert `char c` to binary before my function does other things. However, I am getting errors that I am using `itoa` wrong and am not sure how else to even attempt this part of the function.

The main function is:

```
char *alpha = "abcde";
unsigned char bits[8];

for (int pos=0;pos<5;pos++)
{
    printf( "%c ", alpha[pos] );
    char2bits( alpha[pos], bits );
}
```

The function, for what I have so far, is:

```
void char2bits( char c, unsigned char bits[8] ){
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        itoa(c, (bits)[i], 2);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Use bit shift instead.

Comment: bit X of unsigned char c is found as `(c >> X)  &  1`.

Comment: I have never used bit shift before sorry

Comment: @IgorMassarski Can you provide an example of input and relative expected output?

Comment: @LucaPolito it needs to call a function after that's given and do this, bits 0 through 7 from the character, c and store the bit values in the array bits.

Comment: Please [edit] your question, as comments will get lost or not be read. Please provide an actual example of input and output, like `'a'` -> `"01100001"`, not just some indirect expression.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add requested information or clarification. Don't use comments for this pourpose. It is still unclear what result in `bits` you expect e.g. from the input `'a'`. Do you want the bits of the character encoding (ASCII) of `'a'` which would be `01100001`? Or the bits of the hexadecimal digit `a` which would be `00001010`?

Comment: itoa is conversion int to ascii : second arg is a string aka char[] or char* (not char). And the result in the string is chars which are ´0’ or ´1’ which are different from bit values 0 and 1. And as spotted by @stark is is better to use binary operators.

Comment: I need to get the ascii value of each specific character ie: 'a' to 01100001

Comment: @IgorMassarski Please don't use comments to provide requested information. [Edit] your question instead. Without showing an actual example of input and corresponding output, there are still different possible interpretations. You could expect the elements of `bits` to be binary values `0` or `1` or characters `'0'` or `'1'`, `bits[0]` could be the least or most significant bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible implementation of `char2bits()`:

```c
void char2bits(char c, unsigned char bits[8]) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 8; i += 1) {
    bits[i] = (c >> (7 - i)) & 1;
  }
}

int main(void) {
  char c = 3;
  unsigned char bits[8];

  char2bits(c, bits);
  // now `bits` is equal to {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}

  for (size_t i = 0; i < 8; i += 1) {
    printf("%hhu\n", bits[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much i appreciate the help everyone

Answer (score 0):

First when you want to work with bytes, you should use unsigned char or uint8_t.

This function change a byte into a printable string (you can use printf or puts with "bits" array):

```
void char2bits(unsigned char c, unsigned char bits[8]) {
    int shift, i;
    for(shift = 7, i = 0; i < 8; --shift, ++i)
        bits[i] = ((c >> shift) & 0x1) + '0';
}
```

***What happend ?***

with c = 250 = 1111 1010

first your bits table is empty so:
bits = ""

***Step i = 0:***

(c >> shift) = shift right by 7 = 0000 0001

(c >> shift) & 0x1 = keep only last bit = 0000 0001

((c >> shift) & 0x1) + '0' = ((c >> shift) & 0x1) + 48 = 48 + 1 = 49 = '1' in ascii

so bits = "1";

***Step i = 1:***

(c >> shift) = shift right by 6 = 0000 0011

(c >> shift) & 0x1 = keep only last bit = 0000 0001

((c >> shift) & 0x1) + '0' = ((c >> shift) & 0x1) + 48 = 48 + 1 = 49 = '1' in ascii

so bits = "11";

***Step i = 2:***

(c >> shift) = shift right by 5 = 0000 0111

(c >> shift) & 0x1 = keep only last bit = 0000 0001

((c >> shift) & 0x1) + '0' = ((c >> shift) & 0x1) + 48 = 48 + 1 = 49 = '1' in ascii

so bits = "111";

***Step i = 3:***

(c >> shift) = shift right by 4 = 0000 1111

(c >> shift) & 0x1 = keep only last bit = 0000 0001

((c >> shift) & 0x1) + '0' = ((c >> shift) & 0x1) + 48 = 48 + 1 = 49 = '1' in ascii

so bits = "1111";

***Step i = 4:***

(c >> shift) = shift right by 3 = 0001 1111

(c >> shift) & 0x1 = keep only last bit = 0000 0001

((c >> shift) & 0x1) + '0' = ((c >> shift) & 0x1) + 48 = 48 + 1 = 49 = '1' in ascii

so bits = "11111";

***Step i = 5:***

(c >> shift) = shift right by 2 = 0011 1110

(c >> shift) & 0x1 = keep only last bit = 0000 0000

((c >> shift) & 0x1) + '0' = ((c >> shift) & 0x1) + 48 = 0 + 48 = 48 = '0' in ascii

so bits = "111110";

***Step i = 6:***

(c >> shift) = shift right by 1 = 0111 1101

(c >> shift) & 0x1 = keep only last bit = 0000 0001

((c >> shift) & 0x1) + '0' = ((c >> shift) & 0x1) + 48 = 1 + 48 = 49 = '1' in ascii

so bits = "1111101";

***Step i = 7:***

(c >> shift) = shift right by 0 = 1111 1010

(c >> shift) & 0x1 = keep only last bit = 0000 0000

((c >> shift) & 0x1) + '0' = ((c >> shift) & 0x1) + 48 = 0 + 48 = 48 = '0' in ascii

so bits = "11111010";

***I hope that will help you.***

Comment: thank you so much for explaining it to me

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it

```
void char2bits( char c, unsigned char bits[8] )
{
    for( int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    {
        // create a mask for bit `i`
        int mask = 1 << i;

        // set the corresponding member of the `bits` array to 0 or 1
        // depending on the value of the relevant bit
        bits[i] = (c & mask) ? '1' : '0';
    }
}
```

Hopefully this is clear.

The basic technique is to use the bitwise and `&` operator to strip out a single bit from the input character. The mask will have values 1, 2, 4, 8 etc. as the loop executes. I feed the result of the `&` into the ternary operator `test ? a : b` to store either a "1" or a "0" character in the output array.

This is equivalent to writing out

```
if(c & mask)
    bits[i] = '1';
else
    bits[i] = '0';
```

Note that I've iterated over all 8 possible bits, rather than the 5 that your code used. Note, too, that in the output, `bits[0]` will hold the *least significant bit* of the input character `c`.